# Convert .msg file to .eml file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, msg, eml

I'm writing a wrapper API to send some email reports to a third-party SaaS which parse them and get some information about them. My users have to report with `.eml` or `.msg` file (I am required to accept both formats).
I just found out my SaaS provider does not deal with `.msg` files, so if I forward a `.msg` file with my wrapper, it won't be analyzed by them.

I was thinking a possible workaround: since `.eml` files work just fine, I could convert the `.msg` into `.eml`. In this way I can treat both formats as one and my SaaS will produce their reports.

At the moment I used the python library [https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/[extract-msg][1]](https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/%5Bextract-msg%5D%5B1%5D) to try to parse the `.msg` files, but I didn't found a way to convert it entirely right away.
Also **I would like to run this conversion in-memory if possible**, without saving the output conversion in a file.

Does Anyone know any library I can use or another way to achieve the result?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/JoshData/convert-outlook-msg-file;